# Translated URIs

Tags: localization, url

I'm trying to change the URI of a single so on the german site it will show the translated URI.

At the moment I'm just changing it here:

[image: Screenshot of entry section settings]

However if I try to browse to /Über-uns on the german site I get a 404, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had some stuck tasks so the updated URIs were showing in the settings but the task to actually update them wasn't getting run. Followed instructions here and it worked:

https://craftcms.com/support/stuck-tasks

Answer (score 1):

My experience with foreign characters in the past is that they don't work in URLs. Try changing it to `uber-uns` and see what happens.

Comment: Tried that, even tried changing it to just about-uss but was still getting a 404

Answer (score 1):

Where are you taken when you click the “Open entry” button next to the “Live Preview” one? Maybe you forgot to change the rest of the URL in your tests.

[image: “Open entry” button]

Comment: It just takes me to de.site.com/about-us

Answer (score 1):

When setting up multiple locales you need to also setup sub-directories for each locale except the default one. So if `de` is your third locale you should have a `/de` folder in your wwwroot.

After that please browse to the URL `/de/uber-uns`.

Comment: I have a public_de directory with a separate index.php with define('CRAFT_LOCALE', 'de'); which takes me to de.site.com

Comment: Not www.site.com/de/?